# How can i remove layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created multiple button in a layout dynamically.Now,how can i  remove this layout after used.
for example:-

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);

    parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Primary");

        Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.your_image);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);

        b.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, image, null);
        parent.addView(b);
    }
```

Comment: please consider to accept one of the answers below if it fulfil your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the instance of the linear layout, just call `removeView(...)` as you did for the `addView(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set visibility of linearLayout to gone by `parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

or remove all the views from the linearLayout by `parent.removeAllViews().`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `removeView(View)` or `removeViewAt(position)` from the parent, depending on if you keep track of the indexes or the objects.

```
parent.removeView(button);
parent.removeViewAt(buttonIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

get the parent of the view and remove that view from its parent

```
((ViewGroup) parent.getParent()).removeView(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 View button = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
 ((ViewGroup) button.getParent()).removeView(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had removed ParentView from its child (Textview's) click.

```
tvClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (llContainer.getChildCount() > 1) {
                    ((LinearLayout) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
                }
            }
        });
```